# Preload joined associations matching a condition with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I want to display only the users who have a given skill and the following query works properly:

```
@users.joins(:personal_skills).where(personal_skills: search_conditions).distinct
```

Now in the search results, near a user, **I want to display his `personal_skill`, that matching the `where`condition**.

I can simply use `user.personal_skills.where(search_conditions)` for each user but that would cause the **N+1 query problem**.

How can I avoid that?

I mean, the *Rails-way*, otherwise just iterating over the returned rows would accomplish the task. Indeed each row contains both user data and the joined skill data: the problem is related to the object relational mapping.

Simply substituting `joins` with `includes` is not a solution because that would preload `user.personal_skills` and not the filtered set `user.personal_skills.where(search_conditions)` which is what I want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the users from the `personal_skills`

```
PersonalSkill.joins(:user).where(search_conditions, where(:user_id => @users.map(&:id))
```

with the result you can group the skills by the user